# Map OData results into components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, odata

I'm trying to accomplish filling a list with the results of an OData service, I added the following Rest library into my project: https://github.com/javorosas/react-native-rest-client

I created the client class like this:

```
 import RestClient from 'react-native-rest-client';

    export default class ServiceOrdersOData extends RestClient {
      constructor () {
           super('https://my000000.sapbydesign.com/sap/byd/odata/analytics/ds/Crmsoscb.svc', {
      headers: {

        Authorization: 'Basic X1NFSURPUjpJbmljaW8wMQ=='

      },
    });
  }
       getServiceOrdersOData () {
        // Send the url query as an object
        return this.GET('/Crmsoscb');

       }

    };
```

That is working just fine, now in the actual screen I added a button and handled its onPress event.

```
CallOData(){

        const api = new ServiceOrdersOData();
        const odataValues = api.getServiceOrdersOData();
        console.log(odataValues);
    }
```

If I check the console, I can see that the odataValues is returning all the records from the OData service, which, if executed in the browser comes in the following format:

```
{
    "d": {
        "results": [
            {
                "__metadata": {
                    "uri": "https://my000000.sapbydesign.com/sap/byd/odata/analytics/ds/Crmsoscb.svc/Crmsoscb('.7~0000000000011DDFBEA73CE3794B5D1A')",
                    "type": "CrmsoscbSvc.CrmsoscbType"
                },
                "ID": ".7~0000000000011DDFBEA73CE3794B5D1A",
                "C_DbaServiceOrg": "00000000-0001-1DDF-B9FF-7D69E6266BF2",
                "C_DicIncCataId": "0000000000000000010010000",
                "C_DicIncCatId": "0000000000000000010014172",
                "C_DocId": "00000000000000000000000000000000001",
                "C_DocPostDate": "/Date(1290729600000)/",
                "C_DocSAgCorLc": "3",
                "C_DocUuid": "00000000-0001-1DDF-BEA7-3CE3794B5D1A",
                "C_DpyBuyerCntry": "US",
                "C_DpyBuyerPoscd": "14204",
                "C_DpyBuyerPty": "00000000-0001-1DDF-BA84-90748A78DCE3",
                "C_DpyBuyerRegn": "NY",
                "C_DpyBuyAbc": "A",
                "C_DpyBuyCity": "Buffalo",
                "C_DpyBuyInds": "42",
                "C_DpyBuyIndscsy": "0005",
                "C_DpyBuyNieid": "",
                "C_DpyProcPty": "00000000-0001-1DEF-BAD7-B58B002BEC36",
                "C_DpySalesUnit": "00000000-0001-1DDF-B9FF-7D69E6266BF2",
                "C_DpySrvsupTeam": "00000000-0001-1DDF-B9FF-7D69E6266BF2",
                "C_DpySrvExTeam": "00000000-0001-1DDF-B9FF-7D69E6266BF2",
                "C_DpySrvPerform": "00000000-0001-1DEF-BAD7-B5BC90EE6C36",
                "C_DroMatProcCat": "00000000-0001-1DEF-BA9F-2DABDB415385",
                "C_DroMatProdTy": "1",
                "C_DroRefoIndmat": "00000000-0001-1DEF-BAEB-6DD8248A2BA6",
                "C_DroRefoMat": "00000000-0001-1DEF-BAEA-3DA13AD047A6",
                "C_DsrProcCataid": "0000000000000000010010000",
                "C_DsrProcCatid": "0000000000000000010014000",
                "C_DsrSrvPrior": "3",
                "C_DsrWarranty": null,
                "C_DttInitMonth": "--11",
                "C_DttInitQuartr": "--Q4",
                "C_DttInitRecDt": "/Date(1290729600000)/",
                "C_DttInitWeekdy": "5",
                "C_DttInitYear": "2010",
                "C_DttInitYrmon": "2010-11",
                "C_DttInitYrquar": "2010-Q4",
                "C_DttInitYrweek": "2010-W47",
                "T_DocName": "Combi 75: Below average heat output",
                "NodeId": "0000000000011DDFBEA73CE3794B5D1A",
                "Count": 1
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What I want to do now is fill a list in the screen with those records, let's say with T_DocName and C_DocId.

I know about a function called map, but I have no idea of how to use it in this particular case.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Edit:

So I tried a couple of recommendations, but when I try to get the odataValues.d.results it gives me the following error: `Cannot read property 'results' of undefined`

I believe it is related to the fact that what the response is returning is not a collection but something called Promise? I'm attaching a screenshot of how the console.log of the return itself looks like:

[image: Promise returned]

As you can see in there, there's like a weird structure, and my response is contained under the:

```
_55:
d:{results: Array(291)}
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[StartCaveat]

You need to take a look at the MDN for map: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map the site has an amazing amount of information for all javascript and so much more!

[EndCaveat]

To use map, you must first ensure that the results you want will be inside the array, you can do that by:

```
if(typeof(odataValues.d.results) != "undefined"){
}
```

Now that we know we can access the value and it does, in fact, exist in scope we can use map!

```
  odataValues.d.results.map(item => {
    console.log("DocName", item.T_DocName);
    console.log("CDocId", item.C_DocId);
   });
```

The above will write to console, both t_DocName and C_DocId. However we need to get this data on the screen.

In order to do this we can do the following:

```
<FlatList
 data={this.state.dataToDisplay}
 renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{`T_Doc: ${item.T_DocName} C_Doc ${item.C_DocId}`}</Text>}
/>
```

But wait, we need to create dataToDisplay and what is state?

State is a component level global container that can be accessed anywhere inside your class/function.

To create dataToDisplay let us edit your function.

```
 CallOData(){
    const api = new ServiceOrdersOData();
    const odataValues = api.getServiceOrdersOData();
    if(typeof(odataValues.d.results) != "undefined"){
      this.setState({dataToDisplay: odataValues.d.results.map(item => {
        DocName: item.T_DocName,
        DocId: item.C_DocId
        });
      });
    }
}
```

Great, we have state that contains the value's we need now just add your Flat list to your render, check for data and you are finished!

```
render() {
        return (
          this.state.dataToDisplay && (<FlatList
            data={this.state.dataToDisplay}
            renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{`T_Doc: ${item.DocName} C_Doc ${item.DocId}`}</Text>}
          />)
        )
      }
```

Now you should see your data on the screen! yesssss

Comment: Thanks for your feedback man, I just updated the post with some stuff that I found,  can you give me some insights? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

So you have these odataValues, and should probably save them to state when you receive them. Then, in render, you can render the results like so:

```
return (
   <View> {/* not necessary, this is only a mock of the rest of your layout */}
     {this.state.odataValues.d.results.map(result => <ResultRenderer result={result} />)}
   </View>
 )
```

The ResultRenderer should be a component that renders the props it receives.

I show here how to map the values, since that's what you asked. However, a better performing option is to use a FlatList, since if you have a long list of children, it will only render those on screen, saving on unecessary processing. You use it like so:

```
<FlatList
  data={this.state.odataValues.d.results}
  renderItem={result => <ResultRenderer />}
/>
```

Comment: This answer includes a lot of assumed bootstrapping. For instance, you don't know that the user has state at all. You've assumed it, it can not be implied from their snippet, either. You also seem to assume they will be able to create a secondary component that will display the text. You also seem to assume that odataValues will always have results and those results will always have children.

Comment: I'm not assuming he has state. He has to save some data, and should use state to do so. Also, there isn't any case he wouldn't be "able" to create a secondary component, and I explain it through a secondary component only because it improves readability. However, that can easily be substituted by anything else. Finally, of course a production app should sanitise the input. However, that is not the point of the question, and there is no reason to over-complicate the answer with such things.